# Android XML; How to 'tab' out of the attribute double quotes?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

When I'm typing code in the android xml layout file, I have to write some attributes. However when I'm done I would like to 'tab' out of the double quotes so I can write the next one on a new line.

How do I do that? I have checked the settings > code style, but I can't seem to find it.

`app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"`

So my question is basically, when you look at the above code and your cursor is right before the last double quotes, is how to tab out of that.

Comment: Exactly, I can't understand whats your problem or what do you need to do...

Comment: Do you have the `end` button on your keyboard? If so, then `end`, then `enter`.

Comment: Since in Kotlin I can use the tab to go to the end of the line, is this also possible in XML?